# enzyme is not able to recognize my created child component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a react component consist of my another component and I am using enzyme to test it. Here is my child component rendered in in parent component:

```
    render() {

    let returnVal = "";
        returnVal = <SpinLoader/>


    return (
        returnVal
    )
}
```

So for testing I have:

```
describe("confirmEmail component unit tests", () => {
before(() => {

    confirmEmail = shallow(<ConfirmEmail {...props}/>);
});

// this tests that the Login exists and is not empty
describe("confirmEmail component exists", () => {

    it("should not be empty", () => {
        expect(confirmEmail).to.not.be.empty;
    });
});


})
```

})

the above emptiness test fail since it is not able to recoginze spinloader however if I replace spinloader with a div then it will pass.

Any idea?

** Update:

As soon as I change the returnVal to

```
returnVal = <div><SpinLoader/></div>
```

it works.
so the problem is SpinLoader component which is not a standard element and it is my made component